# How to see each value in a subset of values appears at least once?

Tags: sql

I'm working with a temp table in SQL stored procedure that has two ID columns: `ID1` and `ID2`. `ID1` contains the ID associated with unique samples, and `ID2` contains IDs of normal tests for each ID in `ID1`. In `ID2`, the IDs 1 through 100 can possibly exist, meaning that each ID (1, 2,...,10) can possibly exist once, multiple times, or not at all. Each `ID1` can have multiple IDs from `ID2`.

For example, the temp table could look like this:

```
ID1   ID2
---   ---
1     3
1     4
1     7
1     1
2     2
2     5
2     9
3     8
3     9
```

Is there a way I can check if all IDs in a *subset* of IDs 1-10 exists at least once in `ID2`? For example, is there a way to see if only IDs 2, 3, and 4 each occur in `ID2` at least once?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution to what I was looking for. I don't necessarily have to look at the ID1 column. I only need to see if IDs 2, 3, and 4 occur at least once in ID2. That being said,

```
IF ( (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID2)
    FROM #table
    WHERE ID2 in (2, 3, 4)) = 3 )
```

should only return true if the select finds ID2 = 2, 3, and 4 at least one time.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you really want to check the `id2`s based on the `id1` value.  You can use aggregation and a `having` clause.  For instance, the following returns `id1` that have 2, 3, and 4 in `id2`:

```
select id1
from t
where id2 in (2, 3, 4)
group by id`
having count(distinct id2) = 3;  -- number of items in list
```

EDIT:

If you want to check if all are there you can use:

```
select (case when count(distinct id2) = 3 then 1 else 0 end)
from t
where id2 in (2, 3, 4);
```

This 1 if all exist and 0 if they do not.

Comment: With the logic I'm working on, I only need to check if each ID in that subset appears at least once no matter what ID1 it belongs to. The problem I run into with this solution is that the query only returns an ID1 value only if the ID1 has each ID 2, 3, and 4 in ID 2. So if a sample 1 only has ID2 = 2 and sample 2 has ID2 = 3 and ID2 = 4, the query should return a value.

Comment: @Arch do you mean you want to have something as simple as select id1 from t where id2 in (2, 3, 4)?